# How to obtain ratio of column X over column Y in SQLlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, average, calculated-columns

I am supposed to obtain the following result:
Demographics: Ratio of Men and Women
Write a query that shows the ratio of men and women (pop_male divided by pop_female) over the age of 18 by county in 2018. Order the results from the most female to the most male counties.

```
county  ratio
0   MADERA  0.909718
1   YOLO    0.932634
2   CONTRA COSTA    0.936229
3   SACRAMENTO  0.943243
4   SHASTA  0.944123
```

This preview is limited to five rows.

A select * from population shows base data in this format:

```
    fips    county  year    age pop_female  pop_male    pop_total
0   6001    ALAMEDA 1970    0   8533    8671    17204
1   6001    ALAMEDA 1970    1   8151    8252    16403
2   6001    ALAMEDA 1970    2   7753    8015    15768
3   6001    ALAMEDA 1970    3   8018    8412    16430
4   6001    ALAMEDA 1970    4   8551    8648    17199
```

.....and so on from ages 0-100 for all years 1970- 2018. State is CA

I tried using:

```
select county, (sum(pop_male) / sum(pop_female)) as ratio
from population group by county, year having age > 18 and year = 2018;
```

output was instead:

```
 county ratio
ALAMEDA 0
ALPINE  1
AMADOR  1
BUTTE   0
CALAVERAS  0
COLUSA  1
CONTRA COSTA   0
```

Note: I am aware I haven't done any order by yet as I am not even outputting correct data.

SQLRaptor gave me a suggestion and I tried:

```
select county, (CAST(sum(pop_male) AS DECIMAL(1,6)) / (CAST(sum(pop_female) AS DECIMAL(1,6)) as ratio
from population group by county, year having age > 18 and year = 2018
```

this gave me the response:

> sqlite:///../Databases/population.sqlite3
>   (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "as": syntax error
>   [SQL: select county, (CAST(sum(pop_male) AS DECIMAL(1,6)) / (CAST(sum(pop_female) AS DECIMAL(1,6)) as ratio
>   from population group by county, year having age > 18 and year = 2018]

I took Esteban P's suggestion and used:

select county, (SUM(CAST(pop_male AS float)) / SUM(CAST(pop_female AS float))) as ratio
from population group by county, year having age > 18 and year = 2018 order by ratio

This worked.

Comment: The columns pop_male and pop_female seem like integer values. have you tried to cast them in the SUM funcions like SUM(CAST(pop_male AS float)) ?

Comment: You didn't mention which RDBMS you are using, but it could be you are running into a data type issue, as the SUM returns integers, so the result is an integer as well. 
Try (CAST(sum(pop_male) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) / (CAST(sum(pop_female)AS DECIMAL(9,2)) and replace the DECIMAL size with what's appropriate for your data.

Comment: @SQLRaptor i just tried : (CAST(sum(pop_male) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) / (CAST(sum(pop_female)AS DECIMAL(9,2))  ......................... this gave me the response: * sqlite:///../Databases/population.sqlite3
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "as": syntax error
[SQL: select county, (CAST(sum(pop_male) AS DECIMAL(1,6)) / (CAST(sum(pop_female) AS DECIMAL(1,6)) as ratio
from population group by county, year having age > 18 and year = 2018]

Comment: @EstebanP. that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to override the SQLRaptor's helpful response in comments, but for the sake of completeness :)

SQL treats integer division as integer, therefore truncating it. To avoid that -- cast at least one of the values to a floating point data type (e.g. REAL or FLOAT for SQLite -- check the manual on data types here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)